# Possible cases of matter fields for $SU(2)$ theory which retains asymptotic freedom?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, quantum-chromodynamics, yang-mills, confinement

Let us assume $4$ spacetime dimensions.

QCD, the $SU(3)$ gauge theory with quarks as the matter fields, have the asymptotic freedom property as long as there are 16 quark flavors of mass below the energy scale of interest.

I wonder if there is any similar criterion for the matter fields to $SU(2)$ gauge theory so that asympotitc freedom is maintained?

I tried to find myself but not successful.

Comment: *"I tried to find myself but not successful."* What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function_(physics)) for non-abelian gauge theories. For QCD-like theories at one-loop level, it is given by
$$ \beta(\alpha) = -\frac{\alpha^2}{2\pi}\left(11-\frac{N_c}{6}
-\frac{2N_f}{3}\right) , $$
where $\alpha$ is the coupling constant, $N_c$ is the number of colours and $N_f$ is the number of flavours. It needs to be negative for asymptotic freedom. You can plug in the numbers to see when it works.

Comment: your formula is specific to vector-like theories, SU(2) is special in that it allows for chiral matter (as long as the index is even to avoid the Witten anomaly)

Comment: note also that higher order corrections to the beta function could change the behaviour; e.g. with the conformal window https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/714786/60080